# Group values together based on specified requirements with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The Problem: Need to take each quantity and divide by numbers 2 and 3 and combine with the closet quantity value with the highest transit number. Basically, order by transit descending.

Example: Version A quantity = 15500
Take version A quantity and divide by 3 = 5000 rounded and look for another quantity that is close to 5000. If found then mark these quantities with a 1 in the form column. Do the same thing again but mark those quantities with 2 in the form column and so on. Sometimes it may be necessary to combine two values to get the closest quantity. This will mean you would have 3 forms that have the same form number. An example is below. Form number 2.

Original Data:

```
quantity    divide  transit form
---------------------------------
15500       5166    5       0
1250        416     5       0
5000        1666    5       0
164250      54750   3       0
5250        1750    3       0
6250        2083    3       0
12250       4083    3       0
1750        583     2       0
17000       5666    2       0
2500        833     2       0
11500       3833    2       0
1250        416     1       0
```

Desired Result:

```
quantity    divide  transit form
15500       5166    5       1
1250        416     5       2
5000        1666    5       1
164250      54750   3       3
5250        1750    3       4
6250        2083    3       5
12250       4083    3       6
1750        583     2       5
17000       5666    2       4
2500        833     2       2
11500       3833    2       6
1250        416     1       2
```

The code below is what I have started but the ABS is not giving me the closest and frankly, I am just stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
declare @grp table (Quantity int, divide int, transitdays int, form int);
declare @numberup int;
set @numberup = 4;

with q1 as(
SELECT        a.Quantity, a.transitdays, Form, numberup
FROM            Runlist AS a 
                CROSS JOIN
                (SELECT  SUM(Quantity) AS s
                FROM   Runlist) AS b
)
insert into @grp (quantity, divide, transitdays, form)
select quantity, (quantity / (@numberup -1)) as divide, transitdays, form
from q1

declare db_cursor cursor for
select * from @grp
order by transitdays desc, quantity desc

declare @qty int, @divide int, @transit int, @form int, @search int

OPEN db_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @qty, @divide, @transit, @form
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP (1) quantity, divide
    FROM @grp
    ORDER BY ABS(quantity - @divide);

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @qty, @divide, @transit, @form
END  

CLOSE db_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

Ok, let me see if I can give more context. Lets say I have to print 15500 copies of version A and I have a printing sheet that can hold 4 imprints. I want to divide (normally will be either 2 or 3) the 15500 by a number that gets me to the closest to 15500 on 1 print sheet.

So, I can print the most on 1 print sheet otherwise I will have to spend the money to create another print sheet.

Example: 15500 / 3 = 5166

Now I have 1 slot left out of the 4 on the printing sheet to fill so, I need to find anothe version to run in this slot. Version B quantity needs to be as close as possible to the divided quantity of 5166 or 5000 round to nearest 1000 which will be 5000. In the data I find the quantity 5000 - Version B which I will choose to put in this empty slot on the printing sheet. As you can see how difficult this problem is.

```
Version     Quantity    PrintCount   FormNumber(Print Sheet)  Transit(ship time)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Version A   15500       3x           1                        5
Version B   5000        1x           1                        5
Version C   2500        2x           2                        2
Version G   1250        1x           2                        5
Version H   1250        1x           2                        1
```

The driving factor is to print the versions that have the most transit days. This means these versions have to be shipped first because it takes 5 days to get to the destination.

In the next example I find Version G has to be print early as well because it is 5 day shipping. So, I divide this by 2 = 1250 and print twice on a form. 
I now need to fill 2 slots so I look for numbers close to 1250 which I find 2 version with 1250 to put in the 2 open slots

Humans are doing this now and they want me to automate the process.

Comment: . . As many times as I read this, I still have no idea what your calculations are doing.

Comment: I have tried to give more context above. Hope this makes some more sense.

Comment: I’m confused on your example. Please take Two more values and explain its output

Comment: I have edited the above example.

Comment: Take 12250 it’s form number is 6. 6250 is 5. Please explain how it’s coming.

Comment: This is because both version have a transit day of 3 so, the priority of the print form has less of a factor. At this point I am looking for like quantities to print on a print form that in this case can take 4 imprints. Other factors that will come into play will be print forms that can only take 3 imprints or 2 imprints but this will never be mixed. print forms will always be 2,3 or 4 imprints on a print form. Hope I didn't confuse you more.

Comment: @SGekko, if you can print `164250` at the third batch (4 print forms), why can't you print at once all of the quantities scheduled for `5 transit days` - 15500, 1250 and 5000? `164250/4 = 41062`, is plenty enough to each of these batches, just three forms. Why do you make `15500 = three forms + whatever` instead of `15500 = form 1, 1250 = form 2, ...`? (I'm dumping the fiddle I was working on https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b1753bbe616f5082e267c892960de6f3)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find wich is the closest you can do 2 subqueries on the same set filtering with a WHERE and an ORDER BY, one with values above and on with values below (Order by asc and desc, respectively). Then take the smallest difference between the 2 ones.